# Vector subscript out of range after closing ifstream

Tags: c++, file, stl, copy, fstream

Trying to read a file using ifstream. I came to the following error:
Vector subscript out of range
This happens until I reach the closing statement for the opened file, removing it does not cause an exception.
Here is some sample code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifile("myswearwords.txt");

    if (!ifile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "File not found!\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> myswearswords;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifile),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::back_inserter(myswearswords));

//  ifile.close(); -> exception rased, when I reach th ebrakpoint at this point

/// do further work
return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain me the error here?

Comment: doest this even compile? You forgot `{` after `int main()`. When added, and `ifile.close()` is uncommented, no exception is thrown in my case (added some random text in the myswardwords.txt) I'm using GCC 4.9.3 with c++14 enabled. EDIT: also, you don't include `iostream` but use `std::cerr`. Not sure if that could break the code (expect not being able to compile)

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have posted has some compile time issues:

1. You don't `#include <iostream>`
2. You don't have an open curly brace immediately after `int main()`
3. You don't declare `ifstream ifile`

With all this corrected the code runs fine: http://ideone.com/mzOyE2

Once the data is copied into `myswearswords` there is no preserved connection between `ifile` and `myswearswords`. So you should not be seeing this error.

Now obviously if you're even able to compile you haven't showed us all of your actual code. The actual bug then is likely in the un-shown section of code.

Incidentally, you could improve your code by using the `vector` constructor rater than subsequently copying into `myswearswords`:

```
const vector<string> myswearswords{ istream_iterator<string>(ifile), istream_iterator<string>() };
```